# SQL Group by: Getting count of all distinct values in a column even if the count is zero

Tags: sql

I have two tables for which I am trying query in a certain way-

**Table 1**

| ID | Cust Type | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Active |
| 2 | B | Active |
| 3 | A | Active |
| 4 | A | Active |
| 5 | B | Inactive |

**Table 2**

| ID | ID Type | ID Type Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Type 1 | 1234 |
| 1 | Type 2 | 2345 |
| 1 | Type 3 | 3456 |
| 2 | Type 1 | 4567 |
| 2 | Type 3 | 5678 |
| 2 | Type 5 | 6789 |
| 3 | Type 1 | 7890 |
| 3 | Type 4 | 8901 |
| 4 | Type 5 | 9012 |

I am trying to get the result like this -
**Result**

| ID Type | Count of Active Cust Type A |
| --- | --- |
| Type 1 | 2 |
| Type 2 | 1 |
| Type 3 | 1 |
| Type 4 | 1 |
| Type 5 | 0 |

I have tried different kinds of joins and group by but for whatever reason I do not see the results for the ID type which have a count of 0. So in the example above, I would not see Type 5.

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags, please add the one back that you actually use!

Answer (score 1):

You need the left on the Table1, you want all of those values.  You can put more than * in the count operator.

```
select Table1.ID, count(Table2.ID)
from Table1 left join Table2
on Table1.ID = Table2.ID
group by Table1.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach, valid in T-SQL (Sql Server)
In practice you build 2 temporary tables and left-join them so the type without counts would return a null value and you can COALESCE it at 0

```
SELECT TYPES.[ID Type], COALESCE(COUNTS.TYPE_COUNT, 0)
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT [ID Type] FROM TABLE2) TYPES
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT T2.[ID Type], COUNT(*) as TYPE_COUNT
FROM TABLE2
JOIN TABLE1
ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID
WHERE TABLE1.Status = 'Active') COUNTS
ON TYPES.[ID Type] = COUNTS.[ID Type]
```

I did not try this so it may contains some syntax error, but my goal is to give you the idea

Answer (score 0):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` between tab2 and tab1, and a `COUNT` aggregation.

```
SELECT tab2.ID_Type, COUNT(tab1.ID) AS Count_of_Active_Cust_Type_A
FROM      tab2 
LEFT JOIN tab1 ON tab2.ID = tab1.ID AND tab1.Cust_Type = 'A'
GROUP BY tab2.ID_Type
```

Output:

| ID_Type | Count of Active Cust Type A |
| --- | --- |
| Type 1 | 2 |
| Type 2 | 1 |
| Type 3 | 1 |
| Type 4 | 1 |
| Type 5 | 1 |

Check the [MySQL demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w8fcs1Q2Ggd8dYiFNqpZej/0) and the [SQLite demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w8fcs1Q2Ggd8dYiFNqpZej/1).

**Note**: There's an active Cust Type A for Type 5 as well.